# Checkboxes selected on edit - HABTM models

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 models: `Attorney` and `Powers`.

Where: `Attorney` HABTM `Powers`

When I add a new Attorney, I select many checkboxes that correspond to the Powers.

My question is: When I edit an Attorney, how do make the checkboxes appear selected?

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: If your models correctly define the relationships between them, this should happen automagically, I believe.

Comment: Whats' the exact CakePHP version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually retrieve the HABTM data.

So, for instance, you can use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) and get them like this:

```
$attorney = $this->Attorney->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $id
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Power'
    )
));
```

Then, assuming you name your form-field correctly, they'll populate checked or unchecked automatically.

Without that, you would just be receiving the Attorney data, and the View would have no idea which to check or not.